# Custom database table entry edit page

Tags: plugin-development, database, add-submenu-page

I can display every row of a custom DB table in my custom sub page, but I'm not sure how to implement a single row edit page. Is it as easy as verifying some link query parameter and then displaying "different" page partial using a "if" statement?

For example, "...?id=32bf27a8-dc6a-4064-bcb8-5408d20971fb", then query custom DB for the "id" item and display form to change the entry without displaying the list of other rows?